# Getting subset of records

Tags: mysql

Fiddler Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9579da/3

Given this table of products

```
CountryId   Product Quantity
1   Apple   100
1   Banana  5000
2   Carrot  50000
3   Apple   500
4   Apple   250
6   Apple   6000
```

And this table of available money

```
CountryId   Quantity    Rate
1   4135    0.005
1   870.5   1
1   1000    1
2   7249.71 0.007
2   1788    0.01
2   10  1
2   352 10
3   1900    0.09
4   29877   0.005
5   7108    0.005
```

Where `Rate` represents an exchange rate for the country. Not shown in the money table are seller Ids.

So for the first product, There are 100 apples in country 1. The Pricing for those Apples would be `100 * (0.005)` because there was 4135 available money units for the 0.005 rate, of which we only needed 100 for our apples.

Another example: There are 5000 bananas for country 1. The pricing of those Bananas would be `4135 * (0.005) + 865 * (1)`. There wasn't enough 4135 money units at rate 0.005 so it had to take 865 units from the next available rate which was 1.

I am trying to use this logic and join the money table onto the products table and have a `Price` column. I have no idea how to start because it is not a simple Join

Comment: How is the second table sorted? Note: There is no "next" in SQL without a UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: I don't understand why items would be purchased at a higher rate, if lower rates were available. The whole thing just doesn't malanga sense at present

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The table should be sorted by Rate. You always want the lowest rate and you are tied to whatever is available for your country. If two rates are tied then it really doesn't matter but you could say the higher quantity

Comment: @Strawberry  You wouldn't purchase at a higher rate, if you would always prefer the lower rate until it runs out, then you pull from the 2nd highest rate. However you are limited to your country.

That is why Bananas completely depleted the lower rate of 0.005, and then it had to fall back to the next lowest rate